# How to override attributes in subclass, but maintain methods of super class in python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I want to inherit an attribute in my subclass, but I want to call a method from the super class.

In order to inherit the attribute from the parent, however, I need to call `super` on it.  But when I call `super` on it, it gives it the attribute from the super class, rather than from the sub class.  How do I make sure it gets the attribute that I assigned it in defining the subclass?

```
class SuperClass2(object):
    def __init__(self, passed_in):
        self.attribute = 4
        self.passed_in = passed_in
        self.shared_method()

    def shared_method(self):
        assert self.passed_in == self.attribute, ' sorry they are not equal '

class SubClass2(SuperClass2):
    def __init__(self, passed_in):
        self.attribute = 3  # i set attribute to 3 here
        self.passed_in = passed_in
        super(SubClass2, self).__init__(passed_in)  # I already set attribute to 3 ....but gets overwritten when I call super
```

In the example above, `child=SubClass2(3)` yields `AssertionError:  sorry they are not equal`.

As you can see in the example above, it will not allow me to  the attribute by setting it equal to 3.  How do I override attributes in subclass, but maintain methods of superclass ?

Comment: in superclass:  **self.attribute = getattr(self, attribute, None) or 4**.  if it's been set in subclass it won’t change it else it sets to 4.  might be a bit trickier with falsy values like 0.

Comment: Just call super().__init__ first.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**

The obvious is call `super()` first, then modify attributes

```
class SubClass2(SuperClass2):
  def __init__(self, passed_in):
    super(SubClass2, self).__init__(passed_in)
    self.attribute = 3  # i set attribute to 3 here
    self.passed_in = passed_in
```

**Method 2**

Delegate assigning such common attributes to the super class, always, so it will be like this:

```
class SuperClass2(object):
    def __init__(self, passed_in, attribute=4):
        self.attribute = attribute
        self.passed_in = passed_in
        self.shared_method()

    def shared_method(self):
        assert self.passed_in == self.attribute, ' sorry they are not equal '

class SubClass2(SuperClass2):
    def __init__(self, passed_in):
        super(SubClass2, self).__init__(passed_in=passed_in, attribute=3)
```

**Method 3**

Delegate initialization to a separate method, and then override that method in the subclass

```
class SuperClass2(object):
    def __init__(self, passed_in):
        self._init(passed_in)
        self.shared_method()

    def _init(passed_in):
        self.attribute = 4
        self.passed_in = passed_in

    def shared_method(self):
        assert self.passed_in == self.attribute, ' sorry they are not equal '

class SubClass2(SuperClass2):
    def __init__(self, passed_in):
        super(SubClass2, self).__init__(passed_in=passed_in) 

    def _init(passed_in):
        self.attribute = 3
        self.passed_in = passed_in
```